# Why req.session saved in sessionStore and How to access value from sessionStore

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies

I am using express + passport.js in node.js.
And wants to secure my RestAPI. I have set the token in session as:

```
saveUser = function (req, res) {  
User.findOrCreate({ user_id: req.body.user_id, user_name: req.body.username })
     .success(function(result){
       req.session.token = 'dfgsfd4g564fg456d4gsgsdfg4';
       res.send({status:"ok"});
     }).error(function(error){
         res.send(error);
     }); };
```

but this is set in req.sessionStore.sessions why.?
and every time  key is changed so how to access token from req.sessionStore.sessions.?

```
 sessionStore: 
   { sessions: { E8DRcn3lWkTfAJb3FsPnoeaF: '{"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":null,"expires":null,"secure":true,"httpOnly":true,"path":"/"},"passport":{},"username":"testing.user","token":"3iqZ31YdUaTtyvI6"}' },
     generate: [Function],
     _events: { disconnect: [Function], connect: [Function] } },
  sessionID: 'Ykl9ONPvbxsTOa9Fonb6GFEP',
  session: 
   { cookie: 
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true },
     passport: {} },
```

This configuration in my app.js file.

```
app.configure (function () {
  app.use (express.cookieParser()); 
  app.use (express.bodyParser ());
  app.use (express.methodOverride ());
  app.use (express.session({ secret: 'secret_code' })); // session secret
  app.use (flash());
  app.use (express.json());
  app.use (passport.initialize());
  app.use (passport.session());
  app.use (express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.set ('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use (app.router);
});
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're not supposed to interact with sessionStore, you can always access your sessions on a per-session level in the req.session.

So, to set a token, you've got it right:

```
req.session.token = 'some token';
```

And to access it on the subsequent request, ie. in authentication middleware, you'd check the req.session.token for it, something like this:

```
function someMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    if(req.session && req.session.token) {
        User.validateToken(req.session.token, function(err, valid){
            if(!err && valid) {
                next();
            } else {
                next(new Error('Token not valid.'));
            }
        }); // or something like that
     } else {
        next(new Error('No session token');
     }
};
```

I'm not sure, but I think even passport does something like this with its strategies.

Comment: Hi @Ziatko, Thanks for quick reply. and you are right. I have implemented in same manners. but I did not get value in req.session or req.session.token.

Comment: You also might want to care about how the middleware is set up. Is session() middleware placed before passport middleware? Did you include passport.session? Maybe add your app.js/server.js/whatever main file you use to the question?

Comment: Yes @Ziatko. I have also include passport.session after the express.session. I have updated my question with latest app configuration.